# fixed head and footer and scrolling content in div parent with postion fixed responsive viewpoints

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I need help with some CSS work, what I need is maintaining the same functionality in responsive view when I am using a position fixed in parent div (i am using bootstrap 5).

(the point of this project is in fullscreen view body).

**this is a example of what i need.**
[image]

**and this is what I want in device viewpoint**
[image]

```
<div class="position-fixed bg-dark bottom-0 top-0 end-0 start-0">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    
    <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" title="YouTube video" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

    </div>
    
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    
    <div class="position-absolute top-0" style="height:50px;">header</div>
        <div class="position-absolute h-100">
            <div class="overflow-auto h-100">
            scrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling contentscrolling content
            
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="position-absolute bottom-0" style="height:50px;">footer</div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've shown what you want, but what do you already have? Can you share a minimal example of this layout which is not working how you expect?

Comment: yes i will do give me some time

Comment: now you can take a look, thx

Answer (score 0):

U can use @media in CSS
, which is allow u to make custom styles for a diff screen sizes eg. (mobile, tablet...)
u can check this ,, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp